# How to add custom attribute to Core Data with connection to API?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

First off, I'm not sure how to format the question title properly.

I'm trying to put a new attribute, say `customNote` in a `Codable` `User` model that is both used in **Core Data** and **Rest API**.

With the help of SO and some articles like this https://medium.com/@andrea.prearo/working-with-codable-and-core-data-83983e77198e, I was able to make it work, however without such `customNote` attribute.

**User Model**

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(User)
public class User: NSManagedObject, Codable {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<User> {
        return NSFetchRequest<User>(entityName: "User")
    }

    @NSManaged public var id: Int32
    @NSManaged public var name: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case name = "name"
    }

    required convenience public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        guard let codingUserInfoKeyManagedObjectContext = CodingUserInfoKey.managedObjectContext,
            let managedObjectContext = decoder.userInfo[codingUserInfoKeyManagedObjectContext] as? NSManagedObjectContext,
            let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "User", in: managedObjectContext) else {
                fatalError("Failed to decode User")
        }

        self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: managedObjectContext)

        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int32.self, forKey: .id) ?? 0
        name = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
    }
}
```

**Request**

```
...
            do {
                guard let codingUserInfoKeyManagedObjectContext = CodingUserInfoKey.managedObjectContext else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completion(.failure(NSError(domain: "Error Core Data", code: 0, userInfo: nil)))
                    }

                    return
                }

                let managedObjectContext = CoreDataStack.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.userInfo[codingUserInfoKeyManagedObjectContext] = managedObjectContext
                let result = try decoder.decode(ResponseType.self, from: responseData)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(.success(result))
                }
            } catch let error {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
            }
...
```

Question is, again, how to add a custom attribute? Because the idea is the `customNote` shouldn't be changed during API Call + Sync to Core Data. The `customNote` can be added or edited, and is connected to the `user` instance.

EDIT: the `customNote` is saved locally too. I'm thinking of making a new entity in Core Data for this.

Comment: See the edit. The `customNote` is to be saved locally too, I'm thinking of making a new entity for this.  Not sure if I'm on the right path.

Comment: Have you edited your User entity model to add a 'customNote' attribute, or are you planning on having a relationship to a 'CustomNote' entity (i.e. one-to-many, a user can have more than one note)?

Comment: @richardpiazza If it's possible to have relationship, that would be great. I tried that actually but the problem is whenever I refresh the data of the USER entity, the CustomNote entity gets reset.